Material Icons do not appear to be cropped correctly?
Check out the two images below after I inspect in chrome. These are images from the @mui/icons-material package.
The first when I inspect the svg and then the second when I inspect the path.
My question is why is the svg not cropped as to the path? This is obviously adding "padding" that isn't really there. Why is the icon not cropped like the path is with 0 "padding" or "margin"?
Other icons from this library have less "padding" so displaying them inside my components and adding margin between this and text is going to cause an inconsistent feel to the app.
If I add 4px padding then it's going to be 4px PLUS the fake "padding" here?
Is there any remedy to this?



Can you provide a svg snippet that shows the problem?  I’d guess that the viewbox is the wrong size.

@James if you go here: https://mui.com/material-ui/material-icons/?query=down&selected=ArrowDropDown and then inspect and hover over the svg, you will see the same thing. the viewbox is: viewBox="0 0 24 24

It's the right way to design SVG Icons. All good icon libraries on the internet rely on whitespace to ensure proper placement within their designated space. This spacing helps each icon appear correctly aligned, making it look cohesive when viewed together (next to other icons from the same library).

You need to play with fontSize prop or sx prop to adjust the size. And you can also adjust padding/margin of the elements wrapping MUI icon.
